# Excel macro to split the date and time in one column to two separate columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

The code created by the macro works just fine, but looks clumsy. Can anyone assist in cleaning this up so that I can learn to make the recorded macros cleaner going forward?

```
Sub SplitDateTime()
'
' SplitDateTime Macro
'

'
    Columns("D:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"
    Range("D1:E1").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Time"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INT(RC[-1])"
    Range("E2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
    Range("D2:E2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D3:E212").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Range("G2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    Range("G3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057055/separating-the-date-and-time-in-vba

Comment: there is no good reason why your code should use any `.Select` commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaned and a bit shorter version:

```
Sub SplitDateTime()
'
' SplitDateTime Macro
'

'
    Columns("D:E").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "h:mm;@"
    Range("D1:E1").NumberFormat = "@"
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
    Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Time"
    Range("D2").FormulaR1C1 = "=INT(RC[-1])"
    Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]"
   ' Range("D2:E2").Copy
   ' Range("D3:E212").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
   ' Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("D2:E212").FillDown   ' shorter version
    Columns("D:E").AutoFit   ' added
    Columns("C:C").Hidden = True
    Range("G2").Value = vbNullString
    Range("G3").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To make specific portions of date and time appear in a cell or a formula you have the option to use `=TEXT(data,format)`...

The `format` is the very same as used for `Custom` (`User Defined` in LibreOffice) in the "Format cell" Dialog (CTRL+1).

*Note that there may be "Language & Region" dependent differences in the format specifier; e.g. to specify year in Sweden we need to use "ÅÅÅÅ" while it is "YYYY" for English speakers.

(Also `;` instead of `,` for parameter separation in function calls)*

So
`=TEXT(A1,"YYYY-MM-DD")` will give you a nice ISO:style date for the content in A1.
`=TEXT(A1,"HH:mm")` will present time based on the same date.

These would be show up similar to:
`2023-12-24`
`11:30`

Ref:
https://www.libreofficehelp.com/date-time-formats-libreoffice-calc/#Custom_Formatting_of_Date_Time